# How can I have translations for my subdomain

Tags: subdomain

I setup Craft with one `domain-1`, now `domain-1` has sites `domain-1Global` and `domain-1NL`. On this domain, the translations work perfectly.

But now I added a second domain, `domain-2` with the sites `domain-2Global` and `domain-2NL`. When I access the base url from the `domain-2NL` I get the template for the homepage of `domain-1NL`.

I tried removing the `define('CRAFT_SITE', 'domain-1');` in the web folder, this worked for a while but ultimately failed. Does anybody know a different solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd double-check your `index.php` files for all domains and make sure they're all using the correct handle in the `define('CRAFT_SITE')` code. Sometimes I copy/paste files between sites and forget to update the site-specific variables.

I'd also make sure the Base URL for each site is correct in the settings.

Also make sure the section your homepage uses isn't set to the wrong propagation method.